# WP_Query to get posts in a specific tag or has post_format

Tags: posts, query-posts, meta-query, get-posts

I want to get the posts for two different taxonomies.

I want to list posts only if those posts either have tag longform or the post_format is type link.

I have tried the below code, but it's not working:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
'relation' => 'OR',
'posts_per_page' => 2,
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array( 'post-format-link' )
),
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'space',
    'field' => 'id',
   'tag__in' => array('16') // 16 is the code for tag longform
)
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code :-

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
'posts_per_page' => 2,
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( 'post-format-link' )
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'space',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => array('16'), // 16 is the code for tag longform
        'operator' => 'IN'
    )
    )
));
```

Comment: I increased the number of posts to check , but only getting `post-format-link` post types only, i have only two link posts and getting those only, not the `longform` post

Comment: I have tested this in **post_tag** taxonomy.

Comment: post_tag taxonomy ?? not getting you

Comment: Can you share your updated Code ???